# Matrix with Playa within Playa

Tags: matrix, playa

My head is spinning from this. I've got a Matrix field that contains a Playa field. The entries from that Playa field contain another Playa field that we need to get its title value from. I'm not sure how to get that to work.

So the code would go something like this (simplified for demonstration):

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {matrix_field_name}
        {playa_field_name limit="3"}
            {separate_playa_field}{title}{/separate_playa_field}
        {/playa_field_name}
    {/matrix_field_name}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My **actual code** looks something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
    {wine_styles}
        {suggestions limit="3"}
            {vineyard}{title}{/vineyard}
        {/suggestions}
    {/wine_styles}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Sticking that in a blank test template I end up with something like this:

```
{playa6YpDIoqY:title}
{playa6YpDIoqY:title}
{playa6YpDIoqY:title}
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Not sure how to get this to work. I've looked at other discussions here but they seem a bit different (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to use a var_prefix to get everything to work correctly http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/templating/field.html

Comment: Thanks Sean! Missed the var_prefix bit on Matrix. Did the trick.